# Regex to find if there is a dated content in a web page

Tags: java, regex, spring-boot, seo

I am currently doing SEO based project which crawls a website and stores the page data in a database. So I need to find those URLs which have dated content. That is, if the page data contains date. I am trying to find a regex to check if the page data contains date. I have googled a lot but did not find a solution yet.

Comment: *I have googled a lot* - but what came you up with? Some real code snippets (including the programming language used) would be more than helpful. In the end, you're likely end up using a parser and xpath queries but this might just be an educated guess.

Comment: I have googled  lot - There is no solution regarding checking if the meta data contains any date. every regex is about checking for  a specific date format. I need to check if the html contains date. I am programming using Java.

Comment: Are you looking for a specific date like 12/24/2020 ?

Comment: @sln It can be of any format.. There is no specific formst.  I need to check if a webpage contains date.